# Redirect an specific file from https to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.megabits.es/$1 [R,L]
```

But I tried to create an exception for files in folder /api/ or files inside api (secure.php and xml.php) so they stay on HTTP.

Is this possible?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another condition to it:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.megabits.es/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for all! Done it :)